# Use "Set-ADAccountPassword" to change own password

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm writing a PS script to change an AD account's password by:

- grabbing current user password from a Key Vault
- Create a PSCredential *$credential* using the user's username and password obtained from KV
- Generate new password in plain text and convert to secure string *$newpass*
- Running Set-ADAccountPassword:

  Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity "testuser" -Reset -NewPassword $newpass -Credential $credential

This fails with "Set-ADAccountPassword: Access is denied". The $credential object contains the current user's credentials which are valid (I'm testing this in advance).

As I understand it users have SELF as able to change their own password, as they can just CTRL+ALT+DEL to reset it. In this case, this account is not allowed interactive logins (so I can't test in a PS terminal using RUNAS), and powershell would be an easy wait to change the password periodically.

Why am I getting access denied, and is there a way around this?

Comment: You're not performing a _reset_, you're performing an authenticated _change_ (big difference), remove `-Reset`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen this makes perfect sense, and it's working now. I've removed -Reset and added -OldPassword.

Can you post this as an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of password update operations natively supported by AD:

- Password **Reset**

  - In this operation, permission to update the account password is granted to an administrative user who can then set it without having to know the existing password
- Password **Change**

  - In this operation, the calling user supplies the existing password as an argument, this authenticating the change - this is what you want!

When you specific the `-Reset` switch parameter, `Set-ADAccountPassword` takes it to mean you want to perform a password *reset*.

To perform a password *change* instead:

- Remove the `-Reset` switch
- Pass the existing password value as an argument to the `-OldPassword` parameter

Comment: Thank you for your help! Marked as answered.